# How Do You Create A Transition Bar Chart Plotly Drilldown in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have created a very simple Shiny App and a very simple drill-down plotly chart. However, I would like the drill-down to be a transition instead of a new chart right below it.

So, in this case if you clicked on the City, the chart would CHANGE into the City. There would not be a new chart that populates right below the State chart as is the current version.

Can someone please help me achieve this? Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)





full_data <- tibble(
  State = c("IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN"),
  City = c("Chicago", "Rockford", "Naperville", "Chicago", "Rockford", "Naperville","Fort Wayne", "Indianapolis", "Bloomington", "Fort Wayne", "Indianapolis", "Bloomington"),
  Year = c("2008", "2008", "2008", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2009", "2009", "2009"),
  GDP = c(200, 300, 350, 400, 450, 250, 600, 400, 300, 800, 520, 375)
)






ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "year",
              label = "Year",
              multiple = TRUE,
              choices = unique(full_data$Year),
              selected = unique(full_data$Year)),
  selectInput(inputId = "state",
              label = "State",
              choices = unique(full_data$State)),
  selectInput(inputId = "city",
              label = "City",
              choices = unique(full_data$City)),
  plotlyOutput("state_level", height = 200),
  plotlyOutput("city_level", height = 200),
  uiOutput('back'),
  uiOutput("back1")
)






server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  state_filter <- reactiveVal()
  city_filter <- reactiveVal()
  
  
  

  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "state_level"), {
    state_filter(event_data("plotly_click", source = "state_level")$x)
    city_filter(NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "city_level"), {
    city_filter(
      event_data("plotly_click", source = "city_level")$x
    )
  })
  
  

  
  gdp_reactive <- reactive({
    full_data %>%
      filter(Year %in% input$year) %>%
      filter(State %in% input$state)  
  })
  
  
  
  output$state_level <- renderPlotly({
    gdp_reactive() %>% 
      plot_ly(
        x = ~Year,
        y = ~GDP,
        color = ~City,
        source = "state_level",
        type = "bar"
      ) %>% 
      layout(barmode = "stack", showlegend = T)
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  gdp_reactive_2 <- reactive({
    full_data %>%
      filter(Year %in% input$year) %>%
      filter(State %in% input$state) %>%
      filter(City %in% input$city) 
  })
  
  
  
  output$city_level <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(state_filter())) return(NULL)
    
    gdp_reactive_2() %>% 
      plot_ly(
        x = ~Year,
        y = ~GDP,
        color = ~City,
        source = "city_level",
        type = "bar"
      ) %>% 
      layout(barmode = "stack", showlegend = T)
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  
  output$back <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(state_filter()) && is.null(city_filter())) {
      actionButton("clear", "Back", icon("chevron-left"))
    }
  })
  
  output$back1 <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(city_filter())) {
      actionButton("clear1", "Back", icon("chevron-left"))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$clear,
               state_filter(NULL))
  observeEvent(input$clear1,
               city_filter(NULL))
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2 `renderPlotly`, you'll have two plots. Additionally, when you preset buttons as you have, it isn't really a drill-down. The reason I say that is because when you select a state, it should limit the options of which city or cities you want to see the data for.

The user interface (`ui`)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # selectInput(inputId = "year",
  #             label = "Year",
  #             multiple = TRUE,
  #             choices = unique(full_data$Year),
  #             selected = unique(full_data$Year)),
  # selectInput(inputId = "state",
  #             label = "State",
  #             choices = unique(full_data$State)),
  # selectInput(inputId = "city",
  #             label = "City",
  #             choices = unique(full_data$City)),
  # plotlyOutput("state_level", height = 200),
  # plotlyOutput("city_level", height = 200),

  uiOutput('back'),                          # dropdown menus
  # uiOutput("back1")         

  plotlyOutput('plt', height = 200).         # the plot 
)
```

You'll notice that the `ui` is a lot smaller. I'll use reactive data to create the dropdown menus. That way, whether clicking the dropdown or clicking the graph, the only options available are in the filtered data. (For example, you won't see the cities in Indiana if you've drilled into Illinois.)

The `server`

- You'll only have an `observeEvent` for `event_data` one time because there's only one plot.
- You'll only have one `reactive` call, but you control the reaction with conditions.
- You'll only have one plot, but you'll control what's seen with conditions.
- For `renderUI`, you'll also control it with conditions. This is where you'll create and show your dropdown menus.
- Finally, you'll need an `observeEvent` for each of the dropdown menus.

I'm going to provide my code for the `server` initially. In the end, I'll include your code and my code (where your code is commented out). So you can see what elements in your original code go with the code I've provided. (I've kept the order you had originally for this reason.)

I've added comments in the code so that you could understand what and why I did what I did. However, if anything is unclear, let me know.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # create drill down defaults
  dd <- reactiveValues(
    Year = NULL,
    State = NULL,
    City = NULL
  )
  
  observeEvent(event_data('plotly_click', source = 'plt'), {
    x <- event_data('plotly_click', source = "plt")$x
    if(!length(x)) return()
    if(!length(dd$Year)) {         # if year hasn't been chosen
      dd$Year <- x                 # show all years
    } else if(!length(dd$State)) { # if state hasn't been chosen
      dd$State <- x                # show all states
    } else {
      dd$City <- x                 # show all cities
    }
  })

  gdp_reactive <- reactive({
    if(!length(dd$Year)) {                     # if year not chosen
      return(mutate(full_data, value = Year))  # end reactive statement
    }
    full_data <- filter(full_data, Year %in% dd$Year) # dd is drill down
    if(!length(dd$State)) {                    # if state not chosen
      return(mutate(full_data, value = State)) # end reactive statement
    }
    full_data <- filter(full_data, State %in% dd$State)
    mutate(full_data, value = City)
  })
  
  output$plt <- renderPlotly({            # year not chosen initially
    p <- plot_ly(gdp_reactive(), type = "bar", showlegend = F, # so it looks like only 1 trace
                 x = ~value, y = ~GDP, source = "plt")
    if(!length(dd$State)) {               # year chosen, but state not chosen
      add_bars(p, color = ~value) %>% 
        layout(barmode = "overlay")
    } else if(!length(dd$City)) {         # year and state chosen, not city
      plot_ly(gdp_reactive(), type = "bar", showlegend = F, # remove color
              x = ~value, y = ~GDP, source = "plt")
    } else {
      add_bars(p, color = ~value) %>%     # year, state, and city chosen
        filter(value %in% dd$City) %>% # this doesn't make a difference/ only 1 obs per city/state/year
        layout(barmode = "overlay")
    }
  })
      
  output$back <- renderUI({     # create the dropdown menus
    if(!length(dd$Year)) return('Click the bars to drill down') # tip to get started
    yearInput <- selectInput(
      "Year", "Year",
      choices = unique(full_data$Year), selected = dd$Year # year dropdown
    )
    if(!length(dd$State)) return(yearInput)     # stop here; show dropdown options
    subcat <- filter(full_data, Year %in% dd$Year)
    # if not all states were represented in all years
    stateInput <- selectInput(
      "State", "State",
      choices = unique(subcat$State), 
      selected = dd$State                       # state dropdown
    )
    if(!length(dd$City)) {                      # if no cities, stop here
      return(fluidRow(column(3, yearInput),     # show dropdown options
                      column(3, stateInput)))
    }
    subcat <- filter(subcat, State %in% dd$State)
    # only cities in the drill down state in the drill down year
    cities <- selectInput(                      # city dropdown
      "City", "City",
      choices = unique(subcat$City), selected = dd$City 
    )
    fluidRow(                                   # show all dropdown options
      column(3, yearInput),
      column(3, stateInput),
      column(3, cities)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Year, {  # observe selection from year dropdown
    dd$Year <- input$Year
    dd$State <- NULL
    dd$City <- NULL
  })
  observeEvent(input$State, { # observe selection from state dropdown
    dd$State <- input$State
    dd$City <- NULL
  })
  observeEvent(input$City, {  # observe selection from city dropdown
    dd$City <- input$City
  })
}
```

Here's that server one more time. This time, I've nested my code and your code together. I added `$-----` markers so you could collapse your commented out code if you wanted to. (I did while putting this together.)

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # state_filter <- reactiveVal()
  # city_filter <- reactiveVal()
  
  # create drill down
  dd <- reactiveValues(
    Year = NULL,
    State = NULL,
    City = NULL
  )

#---------- not needed -------------
  # observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "state_level"), {
  #   state_filter(event_data("plotly_click", source = "state_level")$x)
  #   city_filter(NULL)
  # })
  # 
  # observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "city_level"), {
  #   city_filter(
  #     event_data("plotly_click", source = "city_level")$x
  #   )
  # })
  #-----------------------
  
  observeEvent(event_data('plotly_click', source = 'plt'), {
    x <- event_data('plotly_click', source = "plt")$x
    if(!length(x)) return()
    if(!length(dd$Year)) {   # if year hasn't been chosen
      dd$Year <- x           # show all years
    } else if(!length(dd$State)) { # if state hasn't been chosen
      dd$State <- x          # show all states
    } else {
      dd$City <- x           # show all cities
    }
  })

  gdp_reactive <- reactive({
    if(!length(dd$Year)) {                     # if year not chosen
      return(mutate(full_data, value = Year))  # end reactive statement
    }
    full_data <- filter(full_data, Year %in% dd$Year) # dd is drill down
    if(!length(dd$State)) {                    # if state not chosen
      return(mutate(full_data, value = State)) # end reactive statement
    }
    full_data <- filter(full_data, State %in% dd$State)
    mutate(full_data, value = City)
    # full_data %>%
    #   filter(Year %in% input$year) %>%
    #   filter(State %in% input$state)  
  })
  
  output$plt <- renderPlotly({            # year not chosen initially
    p <- plot_ly(gdp_reactive(), type = "bar", showlegend = F, # so it looks like only 1 trace
                 x = ~value, y = ~GDP, source = "plt")
    if(!length(dd$State)) {               # year chosen, but state not chosen
      add_bars(p, color = ~value) %>% 
        layout(barmode = "overlay")
    } else if(!length(dd$City)) {         # year and state chosen, not city
      plot_ly(gdp_reactive(), type = "bar", showlegend = F, # remove color
              x = ~value, y = ~GDP, source = "plt")
    } else {
      add_bars(p, color = ~value) %>%     # year, state, and city chosen
        filter(value %in% dd$City) %>% # this doesn't make a difference/ only 1 obs per city/state/year
        layout(barmode = "overlay")
    }
  })

#---------- not needed -------------  
  # output$state_level <- renderPlotly({
  #   gdp_reactive() %>% 
  #     plot_ly(
  #       x = ~Year,
  #       y = ~GDP,
  #       color = ~City,
  #       source = "state_level",
  #       type = "bar"
  #     ) %>% 
  #     layout(barmode = "stack", showlegend = T)
  # })
  # 
  # gdp_reactive_2 <- reactive({
  #   full_data %>%
  #     filter(Year %in% input$year) %>%
  #     filter(State %in% input$state) %>%
  #     filter(City %in% input$city) 
  # })

  # output$city_level <- renderPlotly({
  #   if (is.null(state_filter())) return(NULL)
  #   
  #   gdp_reactive_2() %>% 
  #     plot_ly(
  #       x = ~Year,
  #       y = ~GDP,
  #       color = ~City,
  #       source = "city_level",
  #       type = "bar"
  #     ) %>% 
  #     layout(barmode = "stack", showlegend = T)
  # })
  #-----------------------
  
  output$back <- renderUI({     # create the dropdown menus
    if(!length(dd$Year)) return('Click the bars to drill down') # tip to get started
    yearInput <- selectInput(
      "Year", "Year",
      choices = unique(full_data$Year), selected = dd$Year # year dropdown
    )
    if(!length(dd$State)) return(yearInput)     # stop here; show dropdown options
    subcat <- filter(full_data, Year %in% dd$Year)
    # if not all states were represented in all years
    stateInput <- selectInput(
      "State", "State",
      choices = unique(subcat$State), 
      selected = dd$State                       # state dropdown
    )
    if(!length(dd$City)) {                      # if no cities, stop here
      return(fluidRow(column(3, yearInput),     # show dropdown options
                      column(3, stateInput)))
    }
    subcat <- filter(subcat, State %in% dd$State)
    # only cities in the drill down state in the drill down year
    cities <- selectInput(                      # city dropdown
      "City", "City",
      choices = unique(subcat$City), selected = dd$City 
    )
    fluidRow(                                   # show all dropdown options
      column(3, yearInput),
      column(3, stateInput),
      column(3, cities)
    )
    # if (!is.null(state_filter()) && is.null(city_filter())) {
    #   actionButton("clear", "Back", icon("chevron-left"))
    # }
  })
  
#---------- not needed -------------
  # output$back1 <- renderUI({
  #   if (!is.null(city_filter())) {
  #     actionButton("clear1", "Back", icon("chevron-left"))
  #   }
  # })
  
  # observeEvent(input$clear,
  #              state_filter(NULL))
  # observeEvent(input$clear1,
  #              city_filter(NULL))
  #-----------------------
  
  observeEvent(input$Year, { # observe selection from year dropdown
    dd$Year <- input$Year
    dd$State <- NULL
    dd$City <- NULL
  })
  observeEvent(input$State, { # observe selection from state dropdown
    dd$State <- input$State
    dd$City <- NULL
  })
  observeEvent(input$City, { # observe selection from city dropdown
    dd$City <- input$City
  })
}
```